# Gallery Permissions for different API on Android

Tags: android-studio, camera

So first of all I want to introduce to my situation. My project is that I could choose a photo in different API's. For example my app is from Kitkat to Marshmallow. That means that I don't need a permission for a Kitkat but I need for Marshmallow. I tested my app and it works great on Kitkat and Lolipop but on Marshmallow I choose the picture and my app crashes. So I'm thinking that the problem is because I get a picture from the user without a permission so I can't edit it(on other API's I can.)

My last code for permissions was:

```
 if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


    } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gallery permission is needed to edit photos.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant

    return;
```

(I deleted it because I don't need it for Kitkat..but i need it for marshmallow :/)
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This example is to access camera,and read/write permission for marshmallow.

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        givePerMissons();

    } else {
        openGallery();
    }  
 public void givePerMissons() {
    if ((Utils.checkPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)&&
            Utils.checkPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        openGallery();
    } else {
        Utils.givePermisson(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Utils.PERMISSOIN);

        if (!Utils.permissionsList.isEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions(Utils.permissionsList.toArray(new String[Utils.permissionsList.size()]), Utils.PERMISSOIN_CODE);
        }
    }
}
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Utils.PERMISSOIN_CODE: {
            if ((Utils.checkPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)&&
            Utils.checkPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                openGallery();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Write Your message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```